# Probability the $X \leq Y$ when $(X,Y)$ is uniformly distributed on the unit disk

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, continuity, polar-coordinates

Given the probability density function $f_{XY}(x,y)=\frac1\pi,$ within the region $\{(x,y):x^2+y^2\leq1\}$, what is the probability $\mathbb{P}(X\leq Y)?$

My solution:

$$\int_0^1\int _{\frac\pi4}^{\frac{5\pi}4}\frac1\pi\,\textrm{d}y\,\textrm{d}x=1.$$

However, I know that my answer is wrong. The correct answer is $\displaystyle\frac12$. I can't detect my mistake.

Answer (score 3):

Easy realize that your joint pdf is constant, thus it is uniform on the unit disk... thus whitout further calculations:

$$\mathbb{P}(X\leq Y)=0.5$$

If you want to integrate you have to do

$$\mathbb{P}(X\leq Y)=\int_0^1\rho\left[ \int_{\pi/4}^{5\pi/4}\frac{1}{\pi }d\theta \right]d\rho=0.5$$

---

Of course the best way to proceed is to look at the following drawing.

[image]

The purple area is the favourable one; it is exactly half of the total area thus, being the joint pdf constant everywhere, the requested probability is exactly 50%

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to get to the answer by integrating?

Comment: @Devis : yes of course. If you want to integrate and use radiants  you have to pass in polars...otherwise you have to integrate in cartesians. Anyway the best way to proceed is to do a drawing realizing that your favourable area is exactly half of the disk

Comment: @Devis : see my answer

Answer (score 0):

you are integrating over rectangle $[0,1] \times[\pi/4, 5\pi/4]$, first you have to apply changing of coordinates to your integral https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Calculus/Book%3A_Calculus_(OpenStax)/15%3A_Multiple_Integration/15.3%3A_Double_Integrals_in_Polar_Coordinates

since your task looks like university assignment I will leave it there :)